# Non-linear differential equation with DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following non-linear differential equation:

```
x y[x] y'[x] + y[x] y'[x] + y[x] y'[x]^3 + 2 x + 2 x y'[x]^2
```

knowing that `y[0] = y0` , `y[l] = epsilon` and `y'[0] = 0`.

How can I solve it using `DSolve`?

Comment: you have first order ode and 3 boundary/initial conditions?

Comment: btw, this ode can't be solved analytically.

Comment: Equate your expression to zero to form a DE.  But it's a tough equation for new user to solve as an IVP with y[x_0]=y0 even numerically and some here expect posting your effort to try so before giving help.  Suggest you first review on-line help with the numerical solver by typing `NDSolve` it in a notebook, hover over it, click on the "I" and study the examples.  Then attempt to code yours and post your code (even if it doesn't work)  above with any errors you get.

Comment: @Nasser `y'[0]=0` is not a new boundary condition, it follows from `y[0]=y0` when $y_0\neq 0$.